# Add product scope to cart-summary.liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I want to loop over product.collections in cart-summary.liquid.
If a product is part of a specific collection, I'm going to display some extra info to the user.

This is not working because, I'm assuming, the cart-summary snippet does not have access to the product scope:

```
{% for c in product.collections %}
    {% if c.handle == "myCollection" %}
        <div>Custom product message here.</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}`
```

Comment: you need to access the product object via cart lineitems here because you can't get product object directly on this file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the use case of this is but if you don't need to display the products separately as a collection just use a product tag instead then loop through the line items in the cart and look for the product tag.

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
   {% if item.product.tags contains 'taggedProduct' %}
        <div>Custom product message here.</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```